# Simulating a continuous-time Markov branching process

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulation, biology

For my MMath dissertation I am exploring the medicinal applications of branching processes, including the Galton-Watson process, Bellman-Harris process ETC. I would like a way for these processes to be visualised and simulated via some code, preferably Python. For the most part, I have been creating arbitrary diagrams using TikZ, I will include some examples below.

**Discrete Time Galton-Watson Process**

[image: Discrete Time Galton-Watson Process]

**Continuous Time Markov Branching Process**

[image: Continuous Time Markov Branching Process]

As mentioned, I would like a way to create these sorts of images using meaningful parameters, rather than my imagination. I have tried working with a number of options, including the *treesim* module from DendroPy. This has been the best option so far, but it has its limitations. Using the following code, I am able to create an output like this:

```
from dendropy.simulate import treesim 

t = treesim.birth_death_tree(birth_rate = 1.0, death_rate = 0.5, num_extant_tips = 10)
t.print_plot()
```

```
                                                           /-------------- T3 
                                            /--------------+                  
              /-----------------------------+              \-------------- T5 
              |                             |                                 
              |                             \----------------------------- T8 
              |                                                               
/-------------+                             /----------------------------- T2 
|             |              /--------------+                                 
|             |              |              |              /-------------- T7 
|             |              |              \--------------+                  
|             \--------------+                             \-------------- T1 
|                            |                                                
+                            |              /----------------------------- T10
|                            \--------------+                                 
|                                           |              /-------------- T6 
|                                           \--------------+                  
|                                                          \-------------- T4 
|                                                                             
\------------------------------------------------------------------------- T9
```

This is a great start to what I am wanting to produce but I have the following problems:

- As can be seen in the code, this is a Birth/Death process simulation, which while being a continuous time Markov branching process, is not general enough for my needs.
- The tree only leads to extinction of the branch, or the creation of two offspring, I'd ideally like something that can model any number of potential offspring, like my second diagram.
- The tree is printed to the console, rather than a figure being created. An output in a similar form to *Matplotlib* with a file I can easily upload and share would be ideal.
- The process tree doesn't look/feel inherently continuous, i.e with exponentially distributed lifetimes, as so many progeny seem to produce offspring at the same time.

This module also has the option to produce discrete-time Birth/Death process trees too, but with the same above problems.

If anyone had any suggestions to Python modules or resources that would help, it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would use sage alias sagemath www.sagemath.org for drawing trees, when these trees come with some mathematical structure. To say more, i would really need more. Explicitly, which tree should be generated (as a sample)? I would quickly write some code if there is interest in this kind of solution. Note: sagemath "is" python plus mathematical "batteries".

Comment: @dan_fulea Thank you for your suggestion, I will certainly look into this. The primary tree I am interested in is one pertaining to a continuous time (Markov) branching process. That is, a process consisting of a single ancestor at time 0, which has an exponentially distributed lifetime. This particle then has a random number of offspring upon death, according to some distribution (i.e Poisson). These offspring act in an identical manner, with exponentially distributed lifetimes, producing a random number of offspring each.